# Bootstrap image resizing for different screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have found a few similar questions but none of them answer exactly what I am hoping for.

I am building a portfolio site, 
I am using bootstrap 3 and would like to have my div box have three images across when on small/medium/large but only two across when on extra-small.

I have the images html housed in div liked this

```
  <div class="row" id="artpieces">
     <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        CODE FOR THE IMAGES
     </div>
  </div>
```

I have been achieving my goal of three images so far with

`#artpieces .col-md-12 img {
    width: 33%;
}`

I have been trying to do something like

`#artpieces .col-xs-12 img {
    width : 49.5%;
}`

but it doesn't make the switch when it gets small. I feel like I am making a very dumb mistake, but can't catch it. (I have tested the %s using a more brute force way one at a time, and they do show up how I want, but it doesn't work when I try both).

PS: this is my first time building a website and I am learning/practicing HTML and CSS. Most of it has been going smooth, but this is the first real issue I haven't been able to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not place each image in a div with the classes `col-md-12 col-xs-12`?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="artpieces">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
              <img src="//placehold.it/300x350" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
              <img src="//placehold.it/300x350" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
              <img src="//placehold.it/300x350" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
              <img src="//placehold.it/300x350" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
              <img src="//placehold.it/300x350" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
              <img src="//placehold.it/300x350" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Live Demo:** http://www.bootply.com/iy3Js8LV5X

Comment: wow, i didn't even consider that. i felt like their should be a much tidier way to do it though. i thought the different class names would pick up the different width instructions when active, but i guess not?

Comment: Your css would work is it was inside of a media query. Without a media query, you are essentially setting the width twice.

Comment: hey thanks for mentioning media query, I looked that up and it made it possible!

Comment: No problem, I was getting to that! I was busy for a second celebrating that it works, thank you very much!